# Manually trigger automount in debian based linux

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, automount

I have formatted a flash drive and thus needed to unmount the device.
Is there a way to trigger automount via command line after formatting was finished ?

(I know I can just reinsert a USB flash drive, but that seems like a cheap shot ;)
And manually mounting seems a bit cumbersome as one needs to mkdir the mount directory manually.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sdc1
```

worked for me. This seems to be what is invoked by gnome according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions.

Answer (score 2):

Here my solution on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
udisksctl mount -b {device}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run

```
sudo partprobe
```

to re-scan all devices for partitions and filesystems. On my Xubuntu 12.04 (debian-based), this also triggers automount.

Comment: Did not work on my Ubuntu 12.04. But I have to admit that for the test I skipped the formatting. (I just unmounted the drive.)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but this could make a difference.